# Davenport Multiplicative Number Theory, pp. 19

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-number-theory

Recently I have been reading the book in
the title of this question to brush my
interest in math up again in the course of
getting a certificate for teaching math
in middle schools.

I know some analysis stuff, but I am pretty
bad at abstract algebra. Thus, I would like
a few helps on resolving some issues rising up
 while reading the book.

Let $v(m)$ denote the index of $m$ relative to
a fixed primitive root $g$, that is, $g^{v(m)} \equiv m (\text{mod $q$})$.

On pp. 18-19, it says as follows:

[Quote begins]

Let $F(\zeta) = \sum_{r = 1}^{q - 1}A_{r}\zeta^{r}$,
and suppose that $F(\zeta)$ has the property that
\[
F(\zeta^{m}) = F(\zeta)
\]
whenever $v(m) \equiv 0 (\text{mod $e$} )$.
Then, by the uniqueness of representation
of a polynomial, we have
\[
A_{r} = A_{s}
\]
whenever $r \equiv sm (\text{mod  $q -1$})$,
and this holds for all $m$ with $v(m) \equiv 0 (\text{mod $e$})$.

Hence $A_{r}$ depends on the residue class $(\text{mod $e$})$ to
which $v(r)$ belongs.

[Quote ends]

I have no idea why the modulus appearing in the quoted part is 
$q - 1$ (and I think
this is why I have no clues at all understanding this part), because $\zeta$ is here supposed to be a $q$th
 root of unity, so that considering $\zeta^{q - 1}$ may not make us go anywhere, or may it?

Besides, I am not sure why the argument concerning $m$ is introduced in the first place. What for?

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What's $A_r$? What's $A_s$? What's $q$? What's $e$? What's $\mu(m)$?

Comment: Let $F(\zeta)$ be any polynomial in $\zeta$, $F(\zeta) = \sum_{r = 1}^{q - 1} A_{r} \zeta^{r}$, $F(\zeta^{m}) = \sum_{s = 1}^{q - 1}A_{s}\zeta^{rs}$ (not sure if this interpretation of $s$ is correct) and suppose that $F(\zeta^{m}) = F(\zeta)$ whenever $v(m) \equiv 0 \text{mod $e$}$ with $q - 1 =  ef$. The goal here seems to be to express $F(\zeta)$ in terms of A's and Gaussian periods. And, I am stuck with what is written in my original question.

Comment: And, $\mu(m)$, although I haven't mentioned at all on that, should usually mean the Mobius function, which takes the value $0$ when $m$ is divisible by any square of primes and otherwise $(-1)^{\text{the number of distinct prime factors of $m$}}$

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include all of this information in it?

Comment: I editted. Awaiting your help.

Comment: Here is what I think. If $r \equiv ms (\text{mod $q - 1$})$ then $\zeta^{ms} = \zeta^{r + (q - 1)k} $ for some integer $k$, and on this, by the supposition on $m$, we have that $(q - 1)k$ is a multiple of the prime $q$, so that $\zeta^{r + (q - 1)k} = \zeta^{r}$. How about that? Did I get it right?